# Displaying rows values in column

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, Am trying to show A1 cell value in C1 and B1 cell value in C2 and vice versa.  not sure how to do this. Is there any way to do this in VBA? Please Help!

[image: Sample]

Comment: Cells(1,3)=Cells(1,1) and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following code

```
Public Sub program()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    i = 1
    j = 1
    Do While Cells(i, "A").Value <> ""
        Cells(j, "C").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
        j = j + 1
        Cells(j, "C").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This works exactly the way i expected. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Little improvement: You can reduce it to only one counter `j` and remove `i` completely by using the following `Cells(j * 2 - 1, "C").value = Cells(j, "A").value` and `Cells(j * 2, "C").value = Cells(j, "B").value` and after that incrementing `j = j + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Do it with the formula: `=IF(MOD(ROW();2)=1;INDEX(A:B;(1+ROW())/2;1);INDEX(A:B;ROW()/2;2))`. Just place it on `C1` and drag it.

Answer (score -2):

Copy and Paste Special - Paste in Cell C1, Tick Transpose Box

Shortcut: Ctrl + C (together) Then Alt , E , S , E (in succession)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i need the result to be displayed VERTICALLY on Column "C"